# how do I de-interlace a camera stream?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-capture

I have an analog camera that returns "both fields interlaced" when I query its format using video4linux API. The pixel format is BGR3 (the fourcc code). I obviously need to de-interlace this stream before I can display it or process it with OpenCV.

I have the Intel IPP installed and use it for all of my format conversions (like I420 to RGB, etc). The Intel API has some routines for de-interlacing but I do not know which one to use.

I also have OpenCV installed--does the OpenCV API have any support for de-interlacing?  I cannot seem to find any.

Any guidance about dealing with interlaced video?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

there is one easy way to de-interlace video:

Remove the even/odd field completely. You can do this by removing even or odd line in every frame. You will reduce half of the resolution by doing this.

Comment: I will try that and see how it looks, thanks for your response